# Attaching a Picture to a point on a chart in Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, image, excel, charts

I was wondering how to attach a Picture from spreedsheet to a point in an Excel chart due to the value of the cells. I have been using this code :

```
Sub Makro()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("D39:O39")
        If cell.Value < Range("D41") And cell.Value <> 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Obraz 18")).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
            ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
            ActiveChart.Paste
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 342
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 19.5
        ElseIf cell.Value >= Range("D41") And cell.Value < Range("D40") Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Obraz 22")).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
            ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
            ActiveChart.Paste
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 342
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 19.5
        ElseIf cell.Value > Range("D40") Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Obraz 19")).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
            ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
            ActiveChart.Paste
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 342
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 19.5
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

But I have to then manually drag the picture over the line on the chart it is representing. Is there a way to convert the point to a chart orientation which I could use as a variable? Or another way?  Thanks